# JQuery drag and drop not working in firefox but works in chrome and and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, drag-and-drop

```
        jQuery("#image-div").on('dragleave',function(e){
            document.getElementById("image-div").style.borderColor = "#E6E6E6";
            return false;
           });
        jQuery("#image-div").on('dragover',function(e){
            document.getElementById("image-div").style.borderColor = "#9B9999";
            return false;
           });
        jQuery("#image-div").on('drop',function(e){
            event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
            var files = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
            if (files.type.match("image.*"))
            {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function (event)
            {
                uploadImage(event.target.result);
            }
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(files);
            } 
            return false;
           });
```

Don't know what is wrong in my code. It is working for Chrome and IE. When Ii drop an image I need to drop it in a div but instead, it opens in a tab.

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined event as e, but using window.event.

```
 jQuery("#image-div").on('drop',function(e){ <-- e
   event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault(); <-event
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. it is start loading and now it is showing "event.dataTransfer" is undefined

Comment: And you adjusted the `function(e)` to be `function(event)`?

Comment: `var files = event.target.files || (event.dataTransfer && event.dataTransfer.files);`

Comment: I do not know drag and drop so I can not help you there, that was a stab in the dark. I just spotted the big error you had with the wrong variable reference.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop Use what they have on the MDN.

Answer (score 0):

one thing just looking at your code i think you need to use **e** instead of **event** unless you are referencing a event out of the events scope that I cannot see.

Comment: Changed code to e but now it is not working in chrome also